# click event on image suddenly doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my relevant HTML

```
 <div class="left">
        <p class="cookie_text"><span id="cookies">0</span> Cookies</p>
        <img src="cookie.png" id="cookie_img" usemap="#cookie_map" alt="Cookie">
        <map name="cookie_map" id="cookie_map">
            <area shape="circle" coords="130,110,140" alt="Cookie" id="map_area">
        </map>
    </div>
```

This is my relevant JS

```
$('#cookie_img').on("click", "img", function () {
    console.log("yea");
    cookieClick(1, true);
});
```

Connection works fine, other click events also do work fine. I had it working before, but i don't have a backup... Can somebody help?

Comment: `$('#cookie_img').on("click", function () {` the first line, you're trying to target the `img` inside `#cookie_img` but `cookie_img` already is the image

Comment: Your delegated event handler is incorrect. `#cookie_img` *is* the `img` element

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`img` is not a child of `cookie_img` hence `event-delegation` will not work!

If you want to use `event-delegation`, use following code considering `.left` left is a static element.

```js
$('.left').on("click", "img", function() {
  console.log("yea");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="left">
  <p class="cookie_text"><span id="cookies">0</span> Cookies</p>
  <img src="cookie.png" id="cookie_img" usemap="#cookie_map" alt="Cookie">
  <map name="cookie_map" id="cookie_map">
            <area shape="circle" coords="130,110,140" alt="Cookie" id="map_area">
        </map>
</div>
```

Comment: or simply use `$('#cookie_img').on('click', function(){ ... })`

Comment: @Dropout — I agree with you but if OP has user `event-delegation`, there might be the case that `#cookie_img` is not in the DOM while attaching event!

Comment: Ah ok, sure you right then. The event should be bound to the closest static object as you say, or even better to the created object itself if it's procedurally generated.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$('body').on("click", "#cookie_img", function () {
    console.log("yea");
    cookieClick(1, true);
});
```